# Meteor Quick Form doesnt submit

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-autoform

im doing the "Intermediate Meteor Tutorial #8 - Insert Permissions, Publishing & Meteor Toys" by LevelUpTuts and my problem is that i cant submit the form i checked the code 5 times but in my opinion everything is right im running meteor 1.4 here is my code

my Recipes.js file

```
Recipes = new Meteor.Collection('recipes');


Recipes.allow({
insert: function(userId, doc) {
    return !!userId;
}
});

RecipeSchema = new SimpleSchema ({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Name"
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        label: "Description"
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        label: "Author",
        autoValue: function() {
            return this.userID
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        },
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        label: "CreatedAt",
        autoValue: function() {
        return new Date()
        },
         autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        },
    },
});

Recipes.attachSchema( RecipeSchema);
```

my recipes.js

```
Meteor.subscribe('recipes');
```

my NewRecipe.js

```
<template name="NewRecipe">
    <div class="new-recipe-container">
        {{> quickForm collection="Recipes" id="insertRecipeForm" type="insert" class="new-recipe-form"}}
    </div>
</template>
```

and the publis.js file

```
Meteor.publish('recipes', function(){
    return Recipes.find({author: this.userId});
});
```

Please help me i dont know what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

i don't have the answer for you (at least not yet), but i'm posting this as an answer so i can provide some formatted code.

you posted some code under NewRecipe.js, but i assume that view code is in NewRecipe.html. Try 2 things:

first, put this code in NewRecipe.js onCreated():

```
SimpleSchema.debug = true;
AutoForm.addHooks(null, {
    onError: function(name, error, template) {
        console.log(name + " error:", error);
    }
});
```

that will enable some debugging for the quickform.

second, in the schema definition, comment out the Recipes.allow() block to see if that's what's blocking saving your data.

then report back on how that goes.

Comment: Hi Zim thanks for your help but i opened my site today again and now the whole site with the quick form doesnt show up. The Flow Router is okay i checked with a test page and with just the word test in it, it showed up but when i putted the command for the quick form in it the whole page was white again --> so i reinstalled quickform but this didnt help so im more left behind than yesterday ;(